# C++ build process - lib dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, windows, build, cmake

I have a Visual studio solution with 5 projects

- Main: application
- A,B,C,D: static libraries

Main depends on A,B. A depends on C,D.

I have a fragile understanding of the build process.

The libs were building alone fine, especially A; I did not feel I was linking C and D to A.

And to build the Main application, I had to have A,B,C and D as input libraries even though Main only directly depends on A,B.

Now I am trying to build he whole thing on Linux with CMake, and I find myself exposed to these linking again. This time I don't want to use brute force and would prefer to understand how this links together.

Should I just build A,B,C and D as .a static libraries and have the Main include them all?

How is it possible for A to build without the symbols from C and D?

Comment: `How is it possible for A to build without the symbols from C and D?` - **Static** libraries are **not linked**, so they needn't symbols from other libraries to be defined. `Should I just build A,B,C and D as .a static libraries and have the Main include them all?` - If this works, why do you need to find other ways?

Comment: For me it just didn't make sense that the application should include second degree dependencies. If the dependencies were deeper, it will mean I will have to include the whole chain.

Comment: You probably want *SHARED* libraries - they are linked with their dependencies, and store that linkage inside.

Comment: I've seen some of the code from my teammates and it involves having additional headers with some confusing macros: __declspec(dllexport/dllimport), that I don't understand till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries are merely archives containing object files (i. e. separately compiled source files). For this reason, when building a static library you don't "link" it, but "archive" it.

Symbols have to be resolved when linking an executable or a shared library. At this point linker tries to resolve all symbols, at if it cannot, you get `undefined reference` errors. But, again, this pertains to linking. Static libraries do not need to have all symbols defined within them.

In your case, if `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are static libs, they will be built independently from each other. The only thing you need to build `A` from `C` and `D` are header files, which are needed by the compiler.

When you are building an executable, you need to specify all static libraries, even if `Main` doesn't "directly" reference symbols from `C` or `D`.

Now, even though static libraries cannot implicitly depend on other libraries, CMake provides a way to express such dependencies on build system level. You can do the following

```
add_library(C STATIC ${B_SOURCES})
add_library(D STATIC ${D_SOURCES})

add_library(A STATIC ${A_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC C D)
```

`target_link_libraries` command above does not cause `A` to be linked with `C` and `D` - as I wrote, that's not have static libs work. Instead, it informs CMake that when linking an executable with `A`, it has to link it with `C` and `D` too:

```
add_executable(Main ${MAIN_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE A)
```

Even though `target_link_libraries` includes only `A`, Makefile generated by CMake will also link `C` and `D` - because they were specified as dependencies of `A`.

---

**dllexport and dllimport**

These two attributes pertain only to shared libraries (DLLs). They control which symbols are exported from a DLL (i. e. accessible from an executable which links to that DLL). [Here's a link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) describing the idea and equivalent on Linux.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! 

Just for the sake of discussion and clarification on a particular case.
If A and B both depend on C, and I do the target_link_libraries(...), will it mean I add the code from C twice when I build Main?

Comment: No, C will be linked only once. CMake will pass libraries to the linker in correct order (because `ld` needs libs in the correct order, when there are dependencies between them), without duplicating them unnecessarily. I think that a lib can be mentioned more than once only when there are circular dependencies between libs.

Btw - if you use CMake's Makefile generator, you can peek at generated commands by setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` to `YES`.